# Storing unicode code points, high-endian or low-endian mode?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

In his famous blog post [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) Joel said :

> The earliest idea for Unicode encoding, which led to the myth about
>   the two bytes, was, hey, let's just store those numbers in two bytes
>   each. So Hello becomes
>
> `00 48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F`
>
> Right? Not so fast! Couldn't it also be:
>
> `48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 ?`

1. The second representation is faster ? why ?
2. How does swapping the high and low bytes affect performance ?

Comment: Endianness is not specific to Unicode. Have you seen this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness?

Comment: @deceze No, definitely to read.

Comment: The sentence "Not so fast!" isn't about computing performance but a way to say "hey, don't make assumptions so fast, here's another way to look at it".

Comment: @Simon If that's what the question is based on: LOL! *"Why does the programmer not get out of the shower? The shampoo says: Lather, rinse, repeat."* X-D

Comment: Thanks @SimonSvensson , your should post your comment as an answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence "Not so fast!" isn't about computing performance but a way to say "hey, don't make assumptions so fast, here's another way to look at it".

The question is [Mu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_%28negative%29).